# $variable not working in SELECT

Tags: php, mysqli

Why would the following SELECT statement be returning the else statement? and a blank echo of $latitude and $longitude

```
$latitude = $_GET["lat"];
$longitude = $_GET["long"];
$pScan="";
$sql = "SELECT id, agent_name, address, url, latitude, longitude FROM enabled_boards WHERE latitude='$latitude' AND longitude='$longitude' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id=$row["id"];
        $agent=$row["agent_name"];
        $address=$row["address"];
        $url=$row["url"];
        $latitude=$row["latitude"];
        $longitude=$row["longitude"];
        $pScan.='  <div id="wrapper">
        <a href="propertyDisp.php?id=' . $id . '" target="_self" >
  <div id="agentIdent"><img src="http://arpad.property/logos/' . $agent . '.jpg"></div>
  <div id="propertyIdent"><h3 align="right">' . $address . '</h3></div>
    </div></a>'; 

    }
}else{
$pScan="No results found,<br>please ensure the property is Arpad Enabled.";
}
```

Whereas replacing the SELECT statement values of $latitude and $longitude with the actual values from the form (lat & long) it successfully echo's both $latitude and $longitude correctly, proving that the values in the form (lat & long) are parsing correctly via the 2 variables.

Using $latitude & $longitude in the SELECT statement breaks it and I can't see why.

Thanks for your help.
Ian.

FORM DETAILS

```
 <form action="scanBoard.php" method="post" name="scanBoard" >
      <input type="text" id="lat" value="52.562292" /><br>
       <input type="text" id="long" value="-0.660871" /><br>
     <div id="boardBtn" class="blink"><input class="button" type="image" src="img/boardBtn.png" ></div></form>
```

*The values have been added to the inputs for testing and will be removed once I fix this issue.

USING $latitude AND $longitude in SELECT statement.

[image: incorrect]

USING 52.562292 AND -0.660871 in SELECT statement.

[image]

Comment: As a note you should not have data from a user or accessible to a user go directly into a query without cleaning the input thoroughly. The code above is a pretty serious case of SQL injection.

Comment: Post your form part too from where you were getting `lat` `long` values

Comment: I'm very grateful for your help and I have tried all of your solutions and none of them work, If I replace $latitude with '52.562292' AND $longitude with '0.660871' I get the expected result and the test echo of $latitude and $longitude also display correctly and are exactly the same as the replacements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always create you query to prevent `sql injection` .Column name and table name is in `backtick`.

```
 $sql = "SELECT `id`, `agent_name`, `address`, `url`, `latitude`, `longitude` FROM `enabled_boards` WHERE `latitude`='".$latitude."' AND `longitude`='".$longitude."' ";
```

And always use `mysqli_connect_errno` to check the error in your query

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

**Updated**

You `forget` `form name` in your `input field`

```
<input type="text" id="lat" value="52.562292" />
<input type="text" id="long" value="-0.660871" />
```

It would be

```
 <input type="text" id="lat" value="52.562292" name="lat" />
 <input type="text" id="long" value="-0.660871" name="long" />
```

And instead of GET method

```
$latitude = $_GET["lat"];
$longitude = $_GET["long"];
```

Use POST method because you use `method="post"` so it would be

```
$latitude = $_POST["lat"];
$longitude = $_POST["long"];
```

Comment: Thanks Saty I do have the If statement too but never posted it as it wasn't the issue, I tried your solution but still no joy :-(

Comment: @user2717917 check updated answer. And this the benefit of post whole code. **WE FIND THAT YOU MISS NAME IN FORM ELEMENT**

Comment: I'm not getting an error because the else statement is parsed Saty , please see the 2 images I posted as it does work just not with $latitude & $longitude in the SELECT statement, theres nothing wrong with the connection it's purely to do with those 2 $variables

Comment: Ok I see the missing name and added it as you asked me to, but it still didn't work, please advise how the echo is displaying the value of the form on the processing page if that missing name element is the problem? as that is coming from the 2 $variables so clearly the values are getting to the page for processing from the form.

Comment: use `$_POST['lat'] AND $_POST['long'] ` because you use `method='post'`

Comment: @user2717917 have you got your problem??

Comment: print_t ?   print_r($_GET) gives me " array( ) "

Comment: Thats the problem use `$_POST['lat'] AND $_POST['long']`

Comment: @user2717917 . That's why we say post your full code

Comment: Thanks for your patience Saty I have it working now, I really appreciate it and I've accepted your answer, now all i have to do is amend the query to return results that are within 15 meters of the 2 $variables. Thanks again for your help. Kind Regards Ian.

Answer (score 1):

Your query has to be

```
$sql = "SELECT id, agent_name, address, url, latitude, longitude FROM enabled_boards WHERE latitude='" . $latitude. "' AND longitude='". $longitude ."'";
```

Comment: I hope the query fix along with the answer suggested by @saty to use $_POST methods worked for you.